# Error: Failed building wheel for wxpython-phoenix while installing wx

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, wxpython, python-3.5

I am trying to install wxpython (I have python 3.5.2(32Bit) and Windows 10(64Bit))
I tried :`pip install wx` and i get: Failed building wheel for wxpython-phoenix 2 times and then a big error line-->

[image: error]

I also tried installing Anaconda, but it did not help.How can I overcome the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of questions about failed installations on windows, probably because the packages are compiled when installed, and sometimes the compilation fail when the compiler is not properly configured. I admit I decided to let the specialized people handle it.

As a nice workaround, you can grab the already built distribution at the official wxpython website located [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds):

Python 3.5 32/64 bit windows:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev2700+c524ed1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev2700+c524ed1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

just download the `.whl` file and do for example:

```
C:\python35\scripts\pip install wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev2700+c524ed1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: It worked when i wrote : pip install wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev2700+c524ed1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl after i coppied the file to C:\Users\''MyUserName'' and tried easy_install wxPython_Phoenix-3.0.3.dev2700+c524ed1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

Answer (score 3):

For linux you need to go here first

https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/

Then grab your linux version and do the install.

(base) fsdfsdfd@linux:~/Downloads$ pip install wxPython-4.1.1-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl

Processing ./wxPython-4.1.1-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /home/orangel/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from wxPython==4.1.1) (8.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy; python_version >= "3.0" in /home/orangel/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from wxPython==4.1.1) (1.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/orangel/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from wxPython==4.1.1) (1.15.0)

Installing collected packages: wxPython

Successfully installed wxPython-4.1.1

if does not works, please try this

sudo apt install libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev