# Anaconda3 on a Windows 10 workstation Installation failure

Tags: python, windows-10, anaconda

Ok, dear friends, in the previous version of this message I had written "Despite my age (I'm almost 62 years!) I have had enough experience of programming in Pascal behind, but I'm an absolute novice in "Machine learning" and projecting Neural Networks in Python, as I would like. So, when I recently tried to download Anaconda3 4.2.0, Python version 3.5, and to install it in my Windows 10 Workstation, I received several error messages". I had obviously underestimated the effects of age ;-),  because finally I realized I had to log in as Administrator, and launch the installation program from inside the "SysWOW64" directory. Now everything is Ok! Thank you everybody for your help!!!

P.S.: the error messages I received before to find the solution were: "unable to run mk_menus" & "unable to run mk_dirs" from _nsis.py file (in the Anaconda3/Lib directory) and "unable to add path Anaconda3 to Windows" from .cio-config.py (in the Anaconda3/pkgs directory).

Comment: Are you sure you download the Windows installer? What is the name of the file you downloaded. Might be time to use Linux. Ubuntu is super newbie friendly. Machine learning on Windows is a pain.

Comment: Francesco, it is awesome that you are undertaking such an ambitious project! I will second @juanpa.arrivillaga's suggestion about checking out Linux for this project. Windows is a decent OS, but Linux has many advantages for developers. Could you perhaps edit your question with the full text of the error messages you are seeing?

Comment: what about standard python 3 + pip install for all needed packages?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: yes, I'm sure. I downloaded both Anaconda2 & Anaconda3 for Windows, and both gave the same installation errors. I'm really interested in Ubuntu server, but I'm waiting to link a Server to my WS before to change OS, but I would like to try Python before!

Comment: @Brendon Dugan: thank tou, Brendon. I'm really interested in Linux OSs, but I'm waiting to link a Server to my WS before to change OS, & I would like to try Python before!

Comment: @FrancescoMaggiore that is unfortunate, as the whole purpose of the Anaconda distribution is to make building a `scipy` stack painless (it was notoriously difficult to build on Windows in the past).  My advice would be to post as much of the error messages as possible, and perhaps start a bounty if this question does not gain more traction in the mean-time. Perhaps you should consider a dual-boot of ubuntu desktop your current computer to just start playing around! This would likely side-step the problem and is very easy to do! It is never to early to switch over to*nix environment!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: honestly I was oriented on Anaconda3 because, wanting to use Python for parallel programming of a neural network, I thought that having available all the support packages from the beginning would be better. But since I can't install in any way neither Anaconda2 nor Anaconda3, I think I will listen your advice and I'll commence downloading Python!

Comment: I figured out that much. I try to stick to the most standard stuff myself. That's where you get more help from more users. You'll make it :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre At lest a year ago, building the stack from scratch using pip in Windows was a *huge* headache. `numpy` and the related packages involve a lot of C, Cython, and Fortran code which needs to be compiled properly. Indeed, `conda` was created as a package/environment manager to deal with non-python dependencies. I also know that as early as about a year ago there was no official 64-bit `numpy` build for Windows!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's why I download the precompiled windows wheels. Compiling on windows with lame VC++ free compiler and the "cannot find vcvars.bat" crap message is just a nightmare. But some specialized people provide the bins. God bless them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432665/error-failed-building-wheel-for-wxpython-phoenix-while-installing-wx/41432965#41432965

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: As I've mentioned above, the errors that are reported AT THE END of the installation process are:
- "Failed to create menus Anaconda";
- "Failed to initialize Anaconda directories";
- "Failed to add Anaconda to the system PATH".
The first two relate to improper execution of "_nsis.py" (positioned in the directory Anaconda\lib), the last to improper execution of ".cio-config.py" (positioned in the directory Anaconda\pkg). Thank you!

Comment: @FrancescoMaggiore next time, add any more details to the original question. You can edit your question, comments are for clarification. I'll go ahead and edit it for you this time.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: Have you tried running the Anaconda installer as an administrator?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: thanks a lot!

Comment: @jmd_dk: sure, jmd, & the system said "NSIS Error: Error launching installer"!

Comment: So you do not have admin permission on the Windows machine?

Comment: @jmd_dk: No, I have! I see the message AFTER launching installer... before it shows the command prompt "C:\WINDOWS\system32" & I had NO error message.

Comment: Please don't deface your question by removing the initial problem details and stating that it's figured out. The point of the site is to ask questions that the community can benefit from. If you solved your problem then answer your question, but leave the problem details for future visitors to benefit from.

Comment: @scrappedcola: sorry, but I am old as age but very young in this community! I'll try to find a remedy adding now which ones were the difficulties I encountered!